# Pointer input issue to template function - probably "programmer error"

Tags: c++, pointers, templates

I am trying to write a couple of template functions that convert back and forth between a value of any data type (within reason) bytewise into a character string. The idea is to (eventually) store the values in a .bin file, and also to be able to recover the values from said .bin file. However, I need to get the conversion functions correct, first. Originally, I wrote a toy function that did both that looked line this:

```
template<typename T>
void buildabin(T x)
{
    char* X;
    T x_;
    X = (char*)&x;
    memcpy(&x_, X, sizeof(T));
    cout<<x_<<endl;
}
```

This seemed to work fine. However, when I tried to separate out the two capabilities, using:

```
template<typename T>
void buildabin(char*& X, T x)
{
    X = (char*)&x;
}
```

And:

```
template<typename T>
void buildaT(char* X, T& x)
{
    memcpy(&x, X, sizeof(T));
}
```

It seems as if it is doing the conversion to the binary string correctly, however, upon input to "buildaT", it barfs - after placing some couts for X in various places, for some strange reason, it is not getting even the address of X correctly. And of course, "little" x just returns garbage.

I have tried every scheme I can to get this to work. It seems it's a "user error" on my part with respect to input in the "buildaT" function, but I am stuck as to where the error lies.

Here is main, if that helps:

```
int main()
{
    //char* G = new char[sizeof(double)]; //(tried this also)

    char* G = NULL;

    double g;

    cin>>g;

    buildabin<double>(G, g);

    double g_;

    buildaT<double>(G, g_);

    cout<<g_<<endl;


    return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here

```
template<typename T>
void buildabin(char*& X, T x)
{
    X = (char*)&x;
}
```

you are trying to set a reference to the address of function parameter, which leaves you with dangling pointer. You probably want `void buildabin(char*& X, T& x)`. However, I have no idea what you are actually trying to achieve, so this answer is somewhat mechanical.

Comment: `(char*& X, T& x)` 
In both functions worked.  Thanks, just needed an extra pair of eyes to look at it.
What I was trying to achieve was clearly stated when I presented my problem.

Comment: And thank you for taking the time to answer my question!